# Autoit: create variant "array of doubles"?

Tags: autoit, autocad-plugin

I'm trying add a point in currently opened Autocad drawning. As reference I'm using VBA example from [AddPoint](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX-Reference/files/GUID-9D3A7DE5-4219-42D8-A2A2-20C723F01ABC-htm.html) manual:

> **VBA:**
>
> `RetVal = object.AddPoint(Point)`
>
> **object**
>
> **Type:** Block, ModelSpace, PaperSpace
>
> The objects this method applies to.
>
> ***Point***
>
> **Access:** Input-only
>
> **Type:** Variant (three-element array of doubles)
>
> The coordinates of the point to be created.

```
Sub Example_AddPoint()
    ' This example creates a point in model space.
    Dim pointObj As AcadPoint
    Dim location(0 To 2) As Double

    ' Define the location of the point
    location(0) = 5#: location(1) = 5#: location(2) = 0#

    ' Create the point
    Set pointObj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddPoint(location)
    ZoomAll

End Sub
```

So far I'm successfully connected to ActiveX object and can get/set many things with it (as long as it requires a string input), except I can't figure out how create a

> Variant (three-element array of doubles)

required for AddPoint function

Here is autoit code I'm playing with:

```
Local $location[3] = [5.0,5.0,0.0]
Local $oAcad = ObjGet("","AutoCAD.Application")
$oAcad.ActiveDocument.Modelspace.AddPoint($location)
```

It returns error:

```
"1.au3" (3) : ==> The requested action with this object has failed.:
$oAcad.ActiveDocument.Modelspace.AddPoint($location)
$oAcad.ActiveDocument.Modelspace^ ERROR
```

There is no details about error even with error handler, so I assume datatype of $location variable is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work but try creating `DllStruct()` as `"double;double;double"` and then either passing it or its `DllStructGetPtr` pointer to COM. Other than that - try asking on AutoIt forums.